# Big Query Public Data

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-analysis, bigquery-public-datasets

How to pin bigquery-public-data to explorer menu after it is under the explorer menu. I am trying since morning but unable to do so.

I searched public in explorer menu and bigquery-public-data is visible under explorer menu but now I don't know how to pin it.

Answer (score 0):

So they changed pin to star. Kindly follow these steps as these were the same steps my friend Lawton recommended and it worked;

1. Type public in the search box
2. Click on broaden search to all projects
3. Click on the star button beside bigquery-public-data
4. Clear the search box
5. Click on narrow search to starred projects

Answer (score 0):

First add data from your explorer menu

[Add Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEgvr.png)

Then Upload file you want to pin

[Upload file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9DBf.png)

Then create table, it will be pinned to your explorer.

[Create Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBn4n.png)

Comment: I've moved these screenshots inline, but this answer would be improved if you cropped the images so they don't contain so much unnecessary whitespace at the bottom. Can you do that?

Comment: There are no empty white spaces in the original file, but I don't know how these white spaces are created under the picture when I upload it, if you could help please.